# combine radio button group with checkbox using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve a radio button group with a check-box attached on the right using bootstrap, as illustrated in the figure below.

Below is some code that fails to create the result. Specifically, the checkbox is floating right, and the borders on the right of B are rounded.

```
<div style="margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px"class="input-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-default"> 
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="A">
            A
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-default"> 
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="B">
            B
        </label>

    </div>

    <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/Br3k9/3/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add the right-chkbox class to the checkbox and the mid-button class to the middle button

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/Br3k9/15/

```
.right-chkbox{
    width: 0px;
}

.mid-button{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```